# Code::Blocks run program with root

Tags: c++, codeblocks, root

I need Code::Blocks to execute my console program with the user root, because otherwise I'm getting an "segmentation fault", on account of lacking rights.

If i run the program with root rights in the shell manually:

[image: running the program manually]

If Code::Blocks builds and runs the program:

[image: run program with code::blocks]

Btw, the function I need to call is `uvc_stream_get_frame`. I'm on a Raspberry Pi 3, Debian Jessie.

So, how can I give Code::Blocks root permissions, in order to run and debug the programs with root user?

Comment: Have you tried running code::blocks with root permissions?

Comment: Why do you *need* root privileges? If you can make your program work *without* requireing elevated privileges, then that would be the better (and safer) solution.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois yeah, I issued **sudo codeblocks**

Comment: Then I don't know codeblocks but I guess you can define a custom command to run the program. If you find it just add "sudo" at the beginning.